# Create a radial (circular) grouped bar chart with d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I am trying to create a radial (circular) grouped bar chart with d3.js, something like [that](https://www.data-to-viz.com/graph/circularbarplot.html).
[image]
To do it, I started from three examples:

- [Radial Stacked Bar Chart](https://observablehq.com/@d3/radial-stacked-bar-chart);
- [Grouped Bar Chart](https://observablehq.com/@d3/grouped-bar-chart);
- [Bar Chart](https://observablehq.com/@d3/bar-chart);

To make it simple, I am using the same data of the first example and I deleted labels and axis, I left only scales's function and arc generator.
I think I am not to far from the final solution, but I can not figure out what I am missing/doing wrong, but I think it could be x0's function or the translate of each bar in the same group. As you can see, no one bar or group is correctly positioned.

I prepare an example [here](https://observablehq.com/@lezan/radial-stacked-bar-chart).

Some code here:

X scale function, to position each group:

```
x0 = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(data.map(d => d.State))
    .range([0, 2 * Math.PI])
    .align(0)
```

X scale function, to position each bar in group:

```
x1 = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(keys)
    .range([0, x0.bandwidth()])
    .align(0)
```

Y scale function, to position height of bar:

```
y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.total)])
  .range([innerRadius, outerRadius]);
```

Arc generator:

```
arc = d3.arc()
    .innerRadius(innerRadius)
    .outerRadius((d) => y(d.value))
    .startAngle(d => x1(d.key))
    .endAngle(d => x1(d.key) + x1.bandwidth())
    .padAngle(0.01)
    .padRadius(innerRadius)
```

Main chain:

```
svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(data)
    .join("g")
      .attr("transform", d => `translate(${x0(d[groupKey])},0)`)
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(d => keys.map(key => ({key, value: d[key]})))
    .join("path")
      .attr('fill', '#69b3a2')
      .attr("d", arc);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yep, you were close. I changed a couple things on your observable that seemed to fix it.

First, in your main graph function, you're using `translate` instead of `rotate`:

```
  // ...

  svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(data)
    .join("g")
      // .attr("transform", d => `translate(${x0(d[groupKey])},0)`)
      .attr("transform", d => `rotate(${x0(d[groupKey])})`)   // use rotate (also remove ',0')
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(d => keys.map(key => ({key, value: d[key]})))
    .join("path")
      .attr('fill', '#69b3a2')
      .attr("d", arc);

  // ...
```

Second, `rotate` as a transform requires degrees, but `x0` returns radians since that's what `d3.arc` needs. The simplest fix I could find for this is just adding a conversion from rads to degs in the `rotate` transform:

```
  // ...

  svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(data)
    .join("g")
      // .attr("transform", d => `translate(${x0(d[groupKey])},0)`)
      // .attr("transform", d => `rotate(${x0(d[groupKey])})`)
      .attr("transform", d => `rotate(${x0(d[groupKey]) * 180 / Math.PI})`)
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(d => keys.map(key => ({key, value: d[key]})))
    .join("path")
      .attr('fill', '#69b3a2')
      .attr("d", arc);

  // ...
```

This gives what I imagine starts to be the correct results:

[image: Grouped Radial Bar Chart]

Comment: This is great! Do you think you could be able to help me with this question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/77218661/6068731 It's also on the circular barplot in D3