# How to make D3 circular barplot responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I have created the following circular barplot using the code [here](https://d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/circular_barplot_label.html). It works fine on a laptop, but not on mobile and I am trying to figure out why. This is my first project in d3 and I tried to read the documentation but the examples of standard barplots don't seem to apply to this case, so I am not sure how to go about it.

> PS: By "does not work" I mean that the chart is not centered, it is not fully visible, and the labels have disappeared.

For reference, a version of this is [here](https://spotify-mood-ring-2a2e81fbe0b0.herokuapp.com/) at the bottom of the page. ( **I have edited the link, there was a generic link earlier**)

This is my `index.html`

## HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/gotham-6" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/styles.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">
    <!-- D3 -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery@master/LIB/d3-scale-radial.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="main-title">Main Title</div>
    </header>

    <!-- Circular time distribution -->
    <h2 class="section-title" style="display: block; margin-bottom: 10px;">Circular BarPlot</h2>
    <div id="my_dataviz"></div>

    <!-- Circular time distribution histogram -->
    <script>

    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    var margin = {top: 0, right: 10, bottom: 30, left: 10},
        width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 460 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
        innerRadius = 90,
        outerRadius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;   // the outerRadius goes from the middle of the SVG area to the border

    // append the svg object
    var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
      .append("svg")
         .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
         .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2 + margin.left) + "," + (height / 2 + margin.top) + ")");

    d3.csv("static/time_distribution.csv", function(data) {

      var maxCount = d3.max(data, function(d) { return +d.count; });

      // Scales
      var x = d3.scaleBand()
          .range([0, 2 * Math.PI])    // X axis goes from 0 to 2pi = all around the circle. If I stop at 1Pi, it will be around a half circle
          .align(0)                  // This does nothing
          .domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.hour; })); // The domain of the X axis is the list of states.
      var y = d3.scaleRadial()
          .range([innerRadius, outerRadius])   // Domain will be define later.
          .domain([0, maxCount]); // Domain of Y is from 0 to the max seen in the data

      // Add the bars
      svg.append("g")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
          .attr("fill", "#1DB954")
          .attr("stroke", "black")
          .attr("stroke-width", 3) // Set the border width
          .attr("d", d3.arc()     // imagine your doing a part of a donut plot
              .innerRadius(innerRadius)
              .outerRadius(function(d) { return y(d['count']); })
              .startAngle(function(d) { return x(d.hour); })
              .endAngle(function(d) { return x(d.hour) + x.bandwidth(); })
              .padAngle(0.01)
              .padRadius(innerRadius))

      // Add the labels
      svg.append("g")
          .selectAll("g")
          .data(data)
          .enter()
          .append("g")
            .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return (x(d.hour) + x.bandwidth() / 2 + Math.PI) % (2 * Math.PI) < Math.PI ? "end" : "start"; })
            .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + ((x(d.hour) + x.bandwidth() / 2) * 180 / Math.PI - 90) + ")"+"translate(" + (y(d['count'])+10) + ",0)"; })
          .append("text")
            .text(function(d){return(d.hour)})
            .attr("transform", function(d) { return (x(d.hour) + x.bandwidth() / 2 + Math.PI) % (2 * Math.PI) < Math.PI ? "rotate(180)" : "rotate(0)"; })
            .style("font-size", "15px")
            .style("font-family", "Gotham")
            .style("font-weight", "500")
            .attr("alignment-baseline", "middle")

    });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

## CSS

These are potentially relevant css styles

```
html {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin-right: calc(-1 * (100vw - 100%));
}
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    min-height: 100vh; /* Set a minimum height for the page */
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Circular', sans-serif;
    background-color: #f3f3f3; /* Set a light background color */
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle at center center, #f5f5f5, #f5f5f5), repeating-radial-gradient(circle at center center, #f5f5f5, #f5f5f5 10px, transparent 20px, transparent 10px);
    background-blend-mode: multiply;
    background-attachment: fixed; /* Keep the background fixed while scrolling */
}
.section-title {
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Gotham', sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #333, #000); /* Gradient background */
    -webkit-background-clip: text; /* Clip text to background */
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent; /* Hide text fill to show gradient */
}
@media (max-width: 500px) { /* 500 should be enough for mobile */
    body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
        width: 100%;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
           -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    html {
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }
```

## Data

Here's the data I am using, although I doubt it makes a difference:

```
hour,count
1,3
2,0
3,0
4,0
5,0
6,0
7,0
8,0
9,0
10,0
11,0
12,0
13,0
14,0
15,10
16,0
17,7
18,7
19,0
20,0
21,0
22,0
23,0
24,5
```

## Screenshot for label issue

this happens both on Safari and Chrome, on my iPhone13 mini.

[image]

Comment: I thought [this](https://perials.github.io/responsive-bar-chart-with-d3/) could be helpful but I can't figure out how to edit it to work with my circular bar plot.

Comment: It seems like the Gotham copy provided by CDN fonts can't be rendered correctly in iOs safari - maybe slightly corrupted invalid. As a workaround you could load an alternative version like [this](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/cf-gotham-fonts?tab=files&path=htf)

Comment: @herrstrietzel this actually worked!

Comment: Glad it helped. Frankly, I can't recommend cdnfonts.com – it's rather slow and also provides some questionable downloads – actually commercial/licenced fonts that might not be free to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Never use SVGs without a `viewBox`

Add a viewbox to your SVG that indicates the actual size of your SVG's contents:

```js
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
      .append("svg")
         .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
         .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
         .attr("viewBox", "0 0 460 460") // ADD A VIEWBOX
```

You generally should always use a viewBox. In my experience, SVGs without viewBoxes do weird, sometimes unexpected things.

(p.s. You may want to use variable inserts vs. hardcoded `460`s)

### 2. Set Max Width

Set a maximum width on your SVG so it shrinks on mobile instead of just getting cut off:

```js
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
      .append("svg")
         .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
         .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
         .attr("viewBox", "0 0 460 460") // ADD A VIEWBOX
         .style("max-width", "100%") // SET MAX WIDTH
```

100% here probably works best since your SVG code has built-in margin. If it didn't, you could instead use css like, `display:block; max-width:90%; margin:auto;`.

### 3. Use the `preserveAspectRatio` SVG attribute

[preserveAspectRatio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio) is the exact solution to your question, but the previous two steps are required for it to work.

At this point, simply setting preserveAspectRatio to something like `xMidYMid meet` will make the SVG contents shrink proportionally on mobile:

```js
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
      .append("svg")
         .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
         .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
         .attr("viewBox", "0 0 460 460") // ADD A VIEWBOX
         .style("max-width", "100%") // SET MAX WIDTH
         .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet") // SHRINK ON MOBILE
```

p.s. Thank you for the full code. It always makes it very easy to solve the issues!

Here's a working version:

```js
const dataSource = "data:text/csv;base64,aG91cixjb3VudAoxLDMKMiwwCjMsMAo0LDAKNSwwCjYsMAo3LDAKOCwwCjksMAoxMCwwCjExLDAKMTIsMAoxMywwCjE0LDAKMTUsMTAKMTYsMAoxNyw3CjE4LDcKMTksMAoyMCwwCjIxLDAKMjIsMAoyMywwCjI0LDUK";

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 0, right: 10, bottom: 30, left: 10},
    width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 460 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    innerRadius = 90,
    outerRadius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;   // the outerRadius goes from the middle of the SVG area to the border

// append the svg object
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
     .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
     .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
     /// ----------------------------------------------------
     .attr("viewBox", "0 0 460 460")
     .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet")
     .style("max-width", "100%")
     /// ----------------------------------------------------
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2 + margin.left) + "," + (height / 2 + margin.top) + ")");

d3.csv(dataSource, function(data) {

  var maxCount = d3.max(data, function(d) { return +d.count; });

  // Scales
  var x = d3.scaleBand()
      .range([0, 2 * Math.PI])    // X axis goes from 0 to 2pi = all around the circle. If I stop at 1Pi, it will be around a half circle
      .align(0)                  // This does nothing
      .domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.hour; })); // The domain of the X axis is the list of states.
  var y = d3.scaleRadial()
      .range([innerRadius, outerRadius])   // Domain will be define later.
      .domain([0, maxCount]); // Domain of Y is from 0 to the max seen in the data

  // Add the bars
  svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
      .attr("fill", "#1DB954")
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .attr("stroke-width", 3) // Set the border width
      .attr("d", d3.arc()     // imagine your doing a part of a donut plot
          .innerRadius(innerRadius)
          .outerRadius(function(d) { return y(d['count']); })
          .startAngle(function(d) { return x(d.hour); })
          .endAngle(function(d) { return x(d.hour) + x.bandwidth(); })
          .padAngle(0.01)
          .padRadius(innerRadius))

  // Add the labels
  svg.append("g")
      .selectAll("g")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("g")
        .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return (x(d.hour) + x.bandwidth() / 2 + Math.PI) % (2 * Math.PI) < Math.PI ? "end" : "start"; })
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + ((x(d.hour) + x.bandwidth() / 2) * 180 / Math.PI - 90) + ")"+"translate(" + (y(d['count'])+10) + ",0)"; })
      .append("text")
        .text(function(d){return(d.hour)})
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return (x(d.hour) + x.bandwidth() / 2 + Math.PI) % (2 * Math.PI) < Math.PI ? "rotate(180)" : "rotate(0)"; })
        .style("font-size", "15px")
        .style("font-family", "Gotham")
        .style("font-weight", "500")
        .attr("alignment-baseline", "middle")

});
```

```css
#my_dataviz {
    width: 250px; /* simulate mobile */
    outline: rgba(0,0,0,0.3) solid 1px;
}

html {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin-right: calc(-1 * (100vw - 100%));
}
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    min-height: 100vh; /* Set a minimum height for the page */
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Circular', sans-serif;
    background-color: #f3f3f3; /* Set a light background color */
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle at center center, #f5f5f5, #f5f5f5), repeating-radial-gradient(circle at center center, #f5f5f5, #f5f5f5 10px, transparent 20px, transparent 10px);
    background-blend-mode: multiply;
    background-attachment: fixed; /* Keep the background fixed while scrolling */
}
.section-title {
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Gotham', sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #333, #000); /* Gradient background */
    -webkit-background-clip: text; /* Clip text to background */
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent; /* Hide text fill to show gradient */
}
@media (max-width: 500px) { /* 500 should be enough for mobile */
    body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
        width: 100%;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
           -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    html {
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/gotham-6" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/styles.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">
    <!-- D3 -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery@master/LIB/d3-scale-radial.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="main-title">Main Title</div>
    </header>

    <!-- Circular time distribution -->
    <h2 class="section-title" style="display: block; margin-bottom: 10px;">Circular BarPlot</h2>
    <div id="my_dataviz"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This looks super promising, but I have a but for some reason, it does not quite seem to work as expected. The good thing is that it is centered and shrinked on mobile. The bad thing is that that labels on mobile are still not shown, there is a grey box around it (both mobile and laptop), and it seems to be shrinked also on laptop. Is there a way to fix this? 

I have pushed it to the website https://spotify-mood-ring-2a2e81fbe0b0.herokuapp.com/ and I am testing from a Mac M1 and an iPhone 13 mini

Comment: Ideally, I would like the plot to take basically all the available width on mobile or laptop, just like the other bits in the page I linked above

Comment: Also, you mention `You may want to use variable inserts vs. hardcoded 460s`. How can I do that? Basically I want to hardcode as little as possible. I've seen this question, but I don't know if it is relevant here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400615/whats-the-best-way-to-make-a-d3-js-visualisation-layout-responsive

Comment: Right so I've figured out that to remove the outline, I just remove the line `outline: rgba(0,0,0,0.3) solid 1px;` but all the other point remains

Comment: Sorry for the grey box. That was to delineate the 'mobile' view. As for hardcoding, the second pair of numbers in `viewBox` are width / height. So, just insert the values you set for the svg's `width` and `height` in the string (I only left it out cuz it was long). I can't reproduce the 'labels not shown' issue, but if I find out anything, I'll reply.

Comment: @Physics_Student, Maybe it's a font problem? Perhaps the iPhone doesn't support woff? You could try `.style("font-family", "Gotham, sans-serif")`. Always good to set fallbacks anyway.

Comment: I've tried setting a fallback for the font, but it did not fix the issue of the labels (https://spotify-mood-ring-2a2e81fbe0b0.herokuapp.com/). Could it be a problem with the box size on mobile?

Thank you for trying. I wish there was a way to have the viewbox automatically calculate the correct size based on the device screen size.

Comment: I have just added a screenshot at the bottom of the question about the labelling issue

Comment: @Physics_Student, when you say, 'calculate the correct size' for `viewBox`, if you just need to keep the aspect ratio (i.e., shrink the height too), you can try using `aspect-ratio`: https://nikitahl.com/css-aspect-ratio - e.g., on the svg, set `width:100%; height:auto; max-width:460px; aspect-ratio:1 / 1`

Comment: Thank you! Would I put this in the Javascript or CSS? I'm a bit confused

Comment: Either, although in the CSS it might be easier. Just select your svg: `#my_dataviz svg { ... }`

Answer (score -2):

Charts where the aspect ratio has to remain the same can be hard to make responsive. One thing you could do is just shrink the whole graph:

```css
.mygraphic {
    transform:scale(0.5);
}
```